# How to watch twitter videos in high quality?

Tags: twitter

I have a decent Internet connection but when I watch videos in Twitter their quality is poor (around 144p). I know that these videos original quality is much better (around 720p). And I know that my Internet connection can handle such load. But Twitter doesn't explicitly allow me to choose video quality. It tries to guess what's better for me but their guess is often incorrect. How can I make Twitter load videos in higher quality?